# If one page can't load or is really slow, you can't open another page on the same website meanwhile: why?

Tags: apache, http

I know this question is a bit subjective but with an example it will me easier:

- http://www.test.com/page1.php : 200ms
- http://www.test.com/page2.php : 200ms
- http://www.test.com/page3.php : Really long, like 2mn
- (another tab) http://www.test.com/page2.php : Won't load until page3.php is loaded on previous tab!

Also, if you open another browser (or start a private navigation window on same browser) and try to load page2.php, it loads in 200ms and does not wait for the previous page3.php.

It's like your "session" is busy with loading page3 and the server won't answer to any other request, but if you open another "session" (another browser) then it's okay.

I suppose this behavior is from Apache, but i can't figure how it exactly works? Is it customizable? Sometimes I wish I could just "stop" the loading of page3.php (which clearly has a programming problem) to continue on other pages, is it possible?

I know this is not really a technical question but this is something I've experienced many times and it really bothers me, I'm probably not the only one.

Comment: If browser1 is slow loading `page2.php`, and during that browser2 is fast on loading `page3.php`, my conclusion would be that this is a browser issue, not Apache.  Apache assigns another worker.  So the workers that are servicing `page3.php` and the other `page2.php` are not linked.  I have seen that often with browsers, each tab in not completely independent of the other.

Comment: This question appears to be more about the operation of the browser, and might get better answers if asked on https://superuser.com/. If you ask the question there be sure to include which browser(s) you've experienced this with.

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't though this could be a problem from the browser, Chromium on Ubuntu in that particular case. I'll try on another one !